# SQL not accepting my comments

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, comments

I am trying to run this sql query in PHPMyAdmin:

```
--create a mysql contact table
--delete contact table if already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;

--create new table named contact with fields as specified
CREATE TABLE contact(
    contactID int PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    company VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(50)
);

--add these to the table
INSERT INTO contact VALUES (0, 'Bill Gates', 'Microsoft', 'bill@micro.com');
INSERT INTO contact VALUES (1, 'Larry Page', 'Google', 'larry@google.com');

--displays whats in this
SELECT * FROM contact;
```

I thought that in sql this is considered a comment: `--I'm a comment`

However PHPMyAdmin isn't accepting it.

I get this error:

```
SQL query:

--create a mysql contact table

--delete contact table if already exists DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact; 


MySQL said: 

Documentation

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 

Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 

use near '--create a mysql contact table --delete contact table if already exists 

DROP T' at line 1
```

I get the same error with the same code on these sql checkers also:

http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/
http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need an interval/space after the `--`

Otherwise it's not considered a valid comment in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You need a space if you use "--" style comments per the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comments.html).  Also add a ";" after your create.

```
-- create a mysql contact table
```

-- delete contact table if already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;

-- create new table named contact with fields as specified
CREATE TABLE contact(
    contactID int PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    company VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(50)
);

-- add these to the table
INSERT INTO contact VALUES (0, 'Bill Gates', 'Microsoft', 'bill@micro.com');
INSERT INTO contact VALUES (1, 'Larry Page', 'Google', 'larry@google.com');

-- displays whats in this
SELECT * FROM contact;

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a space between the the two dash markers and your comment. For example this will not work

```
--This program will run
```

but this will work

```
-- this program will run
```

This is only because I provided a space after the two dashes